# How to Get Data from Workbook into User Form Combox and Text Boxes with Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the data from the other Excel workbook into Userform. So when selected from the Dropdown list the user get automatcally fill the textboxes.

Below is the Code I tried but showing error. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
Private Sub cmbls_DropButtonClick()
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim w As Workbook
 Set w = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Inputs for Gate 1.xlsx")
 Set ssheet = w.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 'showing error in the below line LastRow'
 LastRow = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  
 If Me.cmbls.ListCount = 0 Then
 For i = 2 To LastRow
 Me.cmbls.AddItem Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(i, “A”).Value
 Next i
 End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmbls_Change()
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim w As Workbook
 Set w = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Inputs for Gate 1.xlsx")
 Set ssheet = w.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 LastRow = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 For i = 2 To LastRow
 If Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(i, “A”).Value = (Me.cmbls) Or _
 Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(i, “A”).Value = Val(Me.cmbls) Then
 Me.TextBox1 = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(i, “B”).Value
 End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: "showing Error" is not a useful description of the problem you have...

Comment: If the error is not a compile error arising from your possible misuse of smart-quotes, you should provide more information (and also please revise the code above so that it does compile).

Comment: OP I edited solution to address the error you were having and addressed other errors that you were bound to run into after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to `Smart Quotes` wrapping your sheet and range references.
Remove all `Smart Quotes` with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> & `Find and Replace All` swapping (**“**) & (**”**) for the correct quote notation,  (**"**).

Note the subtle difference betwen the 3 quotes used below. VBA requires the 3rd

### “ <> ” <> "

---

Here are some other updates. You did not declare your worksheet reference and need to qualify all of your objects. This compiles now, but may still produce `Run Time Errors` or may have `Logic Errors` present.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmbls_DropButtonClick()

Dim WB As Workbook: Set WB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Inputs for Gate 1.xlsx")
Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = WB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Long

If Me.cmbls.ListCount = 0 Then
    For i = 2 To WS.Range("A" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Me.cmbls.AddItem Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value
    Next i
End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub cmbls_Change()

Dim WB As Workbook: Set WB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Inputs for Gate 1.xlsx")
Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = WB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To WS.Range("A" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If WS.Cells(i, "A").Value = (Me.cmbls) Or WS.Cells(i, "A").Value = Val(Me.cmbls) Then
        Me.TextBox1 = WS.Cells(i, "B").Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: “Ur so smart” !

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 OP actually had 3 different types of quotes in his code. I didn't notice until I tried to compile it.

Comment: Is that a record you think?

Comment: Thanks alot @urdearboy for the Code it's works perfect, i realised my mistakes and take care to not repeat this mistakes while writing the Code.